# Are Path of War maneuvers broken or balanced?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, balance, combat-maneuver

In my round all chars are currently at level 5. One of the players had a *Path of War* class and got the following two maneuvers: Bronze Knuckle and Steel Flurry Strike.

In combat he used the standard action to activate steel flurry strike and a swift maneuver to activate bronze knuckle.

Now what really shocked me there was the damage output (and with the right combination on how they can be regenerated they can be used again latest every 3 rounds). In total, from what I have calculated a very high strength char can get to **120 damage** easily (**maximum** damage there) and that with 3 attacks being made by him.

Even if we take the regeneration aspect aside that is WAY more than any mage can even dare hope to turn out during the WHOLE combat (and they are then one day off the grid to regenerate the spells).

So my question here is: Is there anything that I'm overlooking here about how maneuvers can be used (like they are not combinable,...) or are war of path maneuvers by far the highest thing possible on the power scale (by far above mages,...)?

*As a note there: An average char has 30 hp a maxed out char about 65 hp at level 5. The maximum damage done with the 3 attacks made here I calculated easily to 120 damage.......about 40 average per hit (thus 3 level 5 chars goners or 2 maxed out level 5 chars).*

Comment: The four close votes so far are all for answers being primarily opinion-based. I'm voting to close, but because I think this is too broad. Revising this question to focus on the balance issues of these two maneuvers in combination is, I think, valid, as, while still opinion-based, that balance can be assessed with some accuracy by an expert. However, judging the balance of the *entirety* of *Path of War* based on these two maneuvers is an overreach and, probably, unfair.

Comment: @HeyICanChan the problem is the adding damage + attacks maneuver can be combined with as good as many other maneuvers (thus more than only those two possible combinations. only at lvl 5 its those two)

Comment: Then maybe emphasizing that specific *mechanic* (and including in the question a few other examples like the one that's already there to demonstrate how that mechanic permeates and, perhaps, unbalances the system) might make the question more specific therefore palatable?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Seeing as *people who wrote Path of War* are members of this website, it may not be so much of a stretch to get, at least, one informed expert (albeit admittedly biased) opinion on the subject of the entirety of the book’s balance.

Comment: @KRyan O, I agree! But this question *as it's phrased* asks for a balance judgment on the *whole* thing based on *one* thing.  That makes me personally uncomfortable. (I am reminded, for example, of the poor reputation of the *Kingdoms of Kalamar* books, which have a couple of unbalanced feats so most *D&D 3e*rs write them off when, in fact, taken as a whole, they're at least *as good* as some of the less respected official books.)

Comment: I think this is just the Pathfinder version of "Are the Tome of Battle classes broken in comparison to other classes and monsters?". I also think that the 3.5 question is not opinion-based and answerable, and I think that there is sufficient evidence that they are not broken compared to either. The GM just has to adjust his strategy in the 3.5 case in regards to encounter design. I feel that there is sufficient enough evidence to argue that PoW classes, likewise, aren't broken in Pathfinder. I also think I gave a reasonable case on why PoW classes aren't broken via my answer despite the -1.

Comment: Whilst you consider a revision, some discussion of exactly this occurred [on the Giant in the Playground forums in 2014](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?376206-What-is-with-the-Broken-Blade-Discipline).

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, Path of War classes are going to be dealing an incredible amount of damage in comparison to spellcasters, but dealing damage is not the most optimal way to play said spellcasters anyway. Spellcasters have a myriad of ways to end encounters without even needing to deal damage i.e. battlefield control, save or suck/dies, debuffing, etc. They also have greater utility capabilities to deal with situations that simply hitting things can't solve. Pathfinder is ultimately a team-based game. The Path of War classes specialize in dealing maximal damage, spellcasters are good at the aforementioned areas, skill-monkeys are proficient at meeting skill challenges, etc.

However,  as Delioth notes: "Never mix Path of War martial classes with Core martial classes. PoW brings the power up notably to help keep them competitive with casters for a while, but this means that a plain-jane fighter won't be able to keep up with anyone". The exception may be the Barbarian, for, as ShadowKras points out, the right combination of stats, feats, rage powers, items, and magic can power up the Barbarian's damage output to comparable levels. However, PoW classes do have a bit more versatility going for them through their maneuvers and can achieve higher damage outputs during the earlier levels. I also think it's worth noting that, if you're a GM having trouble with PoW classes, there are certainly enough spells and SLAs out there to shut them down handily.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51258/discussion-on-answer-by-user3735278-are-path-of-war-maneuvers-broken-or-balanced).